# SQL Server 2008 R2 - how to repair System Views

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 database, which is corrupted. Dbcc checkdb command gives result:

> Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts.
>   Possibly tempdb out of space or a
>   system table is inconsistent. Check
>   previous errors.

Then I tried run `dbcc checktable`, with this command:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' dbcc checktable ('?')"
```

Result of this command is:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
>   should be discarded.

Then I reviewed System Views and found, that some System Views are corrupted, in example when I do

```
select * from [sys].[all_parameters]
```

or `from [sys].[all_columns]` I got some result rows and then I got this error:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
>   should be discarded.

**Is there any ways to repair that System Views?**

P.S. I already tried to do repair with data loss but it was unsuccessful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, your best bet is to copy all the tables to another database.  If you're using SQL Server express, this is something you have to do by hand, using SQL Queries or scripts.

It's a good idea to check for possible causes too: run a memory diagnostic, and a disk check.